# Slow performance of SQL Server when adding count

Tags: sql-server, count, full-text-search

I have an issue in SQL Server where I can't figure out how to solve it. I have a large product table (25m records) with a single full text search column.

Running the following query takes about 1s

```
CHECKPOINT;
GO

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO

SELECT TOP 15
    [ProductID], [EAN], [BrandID], [ShopID],
    [CategoryID], [DeliveryID], [ProductPrice],
    [ShippingCosts]
    --  ,count(ProductID) over()
FROM 
    product WITH (nolock)
WHERE
    CONTAINS(Search, 'Samsung AND Galaxy')
```

To know the total of records I tried different solutions with subqueries etc., but adding `count(ProductID) over()` should be a good solution.

Adding the total count part to the query makes the query very slow. Now it takes about 1m30. Changing to `containstable` instead of `contains` or using `freetext` makes no difference.

I included the execution plan. There are some strange values (868% Table Spool?)

But repopulating the full text index and rebuilding statistics made no difference.

Does anyone have an idea how to speed up the count?

[Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO9Ym.png)

Comment: Be very careful here. You seem to be using NOLOCK and asking performance. That hint is NOT a performance tool. It carries some very heavy baggage that most people don't realize. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows along with a host of other nasty things. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ Unless your testing has proven that you really need that hint (and you can explain the rationale clearly) it is probably best to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the concerns. I know it is not the most liked option. But the update process (which takes 6 -8 hours) is locking the table to long to ignore.
I update the table in a ssis package in badges of 250k from a bulk import table. The insert en update query's lockup the product table.
It is sort of my last resort before duplicating the table and switch after update.
I will look into other options though. As there is always a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking a long time with the count because it has to evaluate the entire table and give you the count. The plan looks like it's finding one of your top 15, seaking the table with the count, then repeating. Without the count, it's just looking at the top 15 from the table after matching the criteria.

This may be faster but still slower than your select without an aggregate function.

```
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO

;WITH cte AS (
select 
       [ProductID]
      ,[EAN]
      ,[BrandID]
      ,[ShopID]
      ,[CategoryID]
      ,[DeliveryID]
      ,[ProductPrice]
      ,[ShippingCosts]
      from product  with (nolock)
     where 
     contains(Search,'Samsung AND Galaxy'))

select top 15
       [ProductID]
      ,[EAN]
      ,[BrandID]
      ,[ShopID]
      ,[CategoryID]
      ,[DeliveryID]
      ,ProductPrice
      ,ShippingCosts
      ,count(ProductID) over()
      FROM cte
```

Comment: As always there is an underlying problem. 
This query was the idea of presenting some first data when the bulk was loaded in the background.

I do need all the data (so i can look up the referenced data for filters etc.) But i was thinking, let first present some items with paging and load filters afterwards.

This query is the base of a larger stored procedure which gets all data and caches it on the webserver. 
I'm affraid that returning 100000+ items just is to much.  Lets get back to the drawing board :)

Comment: I think i expected the full text index to have some count what could be quicker.